# Python3, Pandas - New Column Value based on Column To Left Data (Dynamic)

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have a spreadsheet with several columns containing survey responses. This spreadsheet will be merged into others and I will then have duplicate rows similar to the ones below. I will then need to take all questions with the same text and calculate the percentages of the answers based on the entirety of the merged document.

*Example Excel Data*

```
**Poll Question**                                                     **Poll Responses**
The content was clear and effectively delivered                         37 Total Votes
Strongly Agree                                                          24.30%
Agree                                                                   70.30%
Neutral                                                                 2.70%
Disagree                                                                2.70%
Strongly Disagree                                                       0.00%
The Instructor(s) were engaging and motivating                          37 Total Votes
Strongly Agree                                                          21.60%
Agree                                                                   73.00%
Neutral                                                                 2.70%
Disagree                                                                2.70%
Strongly Disagree                                                       0.00%
I would attend another training session delivered by this Instructor(s) 37 Total Votes
Strongly Agree                                                          21.60%
Agree                                                                   73.00%
Neutral                                                                 5.40%
Disagree                                                                0.00%
Strongly Disagree                                                       0.00%
This was a good format for my training                                  37 Total Votes
Strongly Agree                                                          24.30%
Agree                                                                   62.20%
Neutral                                                                 8.10%
Disagree                                                                2.70%
Strongly Disagree                                                       2.70%
Any comments/suggestions about this training course?                    5 Total Votes
```

My method for calculating a non-percent number of votes will be to convert the percentages to a number. E.G. find and extract `37` from `37 Total Votes`, then use the following formula to get the number of users that voted on that particular answer: `percent * total / 100`.

So `24.30 * 37 / 100 = 8.99` rounded up means 9 out of 37 people voted for "Strongly Agree".

*Here's an example spreadsheet of what I'd like to be able to do*:

```
**Poll Question**  **Poll Responses**  **non-percent**  **subtotal**
  ...                 37 Total Votes     0               37
  ...                 24.30%             9               37
  ...                 70.30%             26              37
  ...                 2.70%              1               37
  ...                 2.70%              1               37
  ...                 0.00%              0               37
```

(note: *non-percent* and *subtotal* would be newly created columns)

Currently I take a folder full of `.xls` files and I loop through that folder, saving them to another in an `.xlsx` format. Inside that loop, I've added a comment block that contains my `# NEW test CODE` where I'm trying to put the logic to do this.

As you can see, I'm trying to target the cell and get the value, then get some regex and extract the number from it, (then add it to the `subtotal` column in that row. I then want to add it till I see a new instance of a row containing `x Total Votes`.

*Here's my current code*:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

files = get_files('/excels/', '.xls')
df_array = []

for i, f in enumerate(files, start=1):
    sheet = pd.read_html(f, attrs={'class' : 'reportData'}, flavor='bs4')
    event_id = get_event_id(pd.read_html(f, attrs={'id' : 'eventSummary'}))
    event_title= get_event_title(pd.read_html(f, attrs={'id' : 'eventSummary'}))
    filename = event_id + '.xlsx'
    rel_path = 'xlsx/' + filename
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(rel_path)

    for df in sheet:
        # NEW test CODE
        q_total = 0
        df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
        if df[df['Poll Responses'].str.contains("Total Votes")]:
        # if df['Poll Responses'].str.contains("Total Votes"):
            q_total = re.findall(r'.+?(?=\sTotal\sVotes)', df['Poll Responses'].str.contains("Total Votes"))[0]
            print(q_total)
        # df['Question Total'] = np.where(df['Poll Responses'].str.contains("Total Votes"), 'yes', 'no')
        # END NEW test Code
        df.insert(0, 'Event ID', event_id)
        df.insert(1, 'Event Title', event_title)
        df.to_excel(writer,'sheet')
        writer.save()

    # progress of entire list
    if i <= len(files):
        print('\r{:*^10}{:.0f}%'.format('Converting: ', i/len(files)*100), end='')

print('\n')
```

**TL;DR**
This seems very convoluted, but if I can get the two *new* columns that contain the total votes for a question and the number (not percentage) of votes for an answer, then I can do some `VLOOKUP` magic for this on the merged document. Any help or methodology suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Will you always have the same number of answers for each question? You can just read in each sheet to a dataframe, them add them together. Pandas figures out the rest.

Comment: Sadly, no. cause there could be "comment box" kind of questions, and it won't be spaced 5 rows from others. Or the users may choose not to do the likert style questoins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, I'll post the pseudo code below:

1. I loop through each sheet. Inside that loop, I loop through each row using `for n, row in enumerate(df.itertuples(), 1):`.
2. I get the value of the field that might contain "Poll Response" `poll_response = str(row[3])`
3. Using an `if` / `else` I check if the `poll_response` contains the text "Total Votes". If it does, it must be a question, otherwise it must be a row with an answer.
4. In the `if` for the question I get the cells that contain the data I need. I then have a function that compares the question text with all objects question text in the array. If it's a match, then I simply update the fields of the object, otherwise I create a new question object.
5. `else` the row is an answer row, and I use the question text to find the object in the array and update/add the answers or data.
6. This process loops through all the rows in each spreadsheet, and now I have my array full of unique question objects.